# Thermodynamics Relevance to String Theory, Advice

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, string-theory, quantum-gravity

Please help me make a very important decision! I only need to hear a bit from a String Theorist or Quantum Field Theorist (or anyone close to such people and areas of research) to tell me about how relevant thermodynamics as a second year module will be for a String Theory career path. Is it one of those you-only-need-a-basic-understanding-and-so-you-can-pick-it-up-later-or-maybe-even-forget-it-and-never-need-it subject to String Theory? I have a strong feeling I will not need it *OR IF I DO* it would probably only be 5% like what heat and temperature is, the laws of thermodynamics, entropy and that's it. I can't imagine needing to know about the ideal gas equation (and if I do it will be something I could pick up whilst doing a PhD in String Theory). I know for a fact that I will need things like EMF, relativity, quantum mechanics, QFT and so on but thermodynamics, as I already, is probably something I will forget about from the time I do it (second year BSc) all the way to the time I begin String Theory (PhD). Also, yes, my university does teach String Theory at PhD level and even offers it at an introductory level at MSc.

Comment: Currently wondering a bit about the relevance/prerequisite-ness of statistical mechanics, which might itself have thermodynamics as a prerequisite. Not too sure but it is just a thought.

Comment: @bolbteppa Hi. I wanted to hear a bit more from you if you wouldn't mind before I decide to close this question. I also hate my thermodynamics module because of the teaching quality so it might be a nicer experience if I get some better lecturer or guidance towards a better textbook at the time of a PhD. I feel like this module is best to be taken lightly without giving too much effort which (to me) means around 60%. I think 40% is a pass and I could easily get 60 or 70 but wouldn't want to stress myself towards 70-90, unlike with maths and QM which I definitely plan on going all out for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a strange question, unless I've misunderstood, as you're asking more about university module advice as opposed to a more general question about thermodynamics & string theory (as the title implies)? It'd be helpful to know if you're asking whether you should pick it over a different module, or just whether you can not study very hard in it, or something different?

Regardless, working in/on string theory is a much wider field than just a few specific research topics, and there are undoubtedly many areas where thermodynamics is not just necessary but integral to the work. Just look at the whole field of black hole thermodynamics in string theory for example. Similarly, there are many areas where it won't be directly useful and will have little impact on the majority of the work done. Overall I'd definitely say that thermodynamics in general, encompassing such a large amount of physics, plays a big enough role in string theory/quantum gravity that it shouldn't be discounted as being irrelevant or not useful for those topics.

However, in 2nd year of undergrad your modules should be based around your general (theoretical) physics knowledge, not just what you presume will be useful for a potential PhD.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for the time to answer this. Also, I saw the subtle diplomatic change in your paragraph to give a more "safe" answer, not knowing my personal situation exactly. Let me fill you in. I can choose to take this module during an LSR (Long Summer Resit period). This means I can focus on the next semester earlier. I also don't feel like I am going to need an A-grade level of practice in thermodynamics and that a B-grade type of effort is enough. As for the maths and qm modules, I will be putting an A* and above level of effort into them and try to get ahead of my planned courses.

Comment: Due to a lack of time and circumstances, it just won't be possible to get as high and ambitiously far as I can whilst at the same time giving an A-grade amount of effort into thermodynamics. This is also hugely to do with an INCREDIBLY terrible lecturer, who isn't necessarily bad at thermodynamics (by far from this!) but rather just not good at the art of teaching. Textbooks? Yes they are bad too but not as much. Let's not get into that too much though

Comment: Oh by the way, I can't get out of doing this module. What I can do, however, is to delay it for the long holiday period.

Comment: @CaptainHD haha well I realised I shouldn't presume too much. I don't think there's a clear cut answer to the question of whether you'll need it, but I think it'd be a shame to miss out on a really important area of physics; black hole thermodynamics and entropy in relation to high-energy physics are super interesting! You also rightly said about statistical mechanics being an important area. My advice would be to try and find a good textbook/lecture notes and get a solid understanding of the topic, but don't overly worry about advanced material - you can learn that later if you need to.

Comment: Genuinely, thank you!     .............. how do I close a question?

Comment: @CaptainHD you should be able to accept my given answer?